# What is za and what is next

Tags: ruby

I found the following ruby code. It translate from `a-z` to `b-za`.

Q1. What is `za`?

Q2. Are `zb, zc` etc. the next?

Q3. Is there `zz`? If it is, then what is after `zz`?

```
while s = gets
  until s =~ /that|the|this/
    s.tr!('a-z', 'b-za')
  end
  puts s
end
```

Comment: I think that 'a-z' and 'b-z a' is the best explanation of what happen here. 'a' become 'b', 'i' become 'i+1', 'z' become 'a'. cycle shift, hah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-tr) allows `c1-c2` as a shorthand notation for a *range* of characters:

- `a-z` expands to `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
- `b-z` expands to `bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`
- `b-za` is `b-z` followed by a single `a`, i.e. `bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza`

Finally `s.tr!('a-z', 'b-za')` replaces each letter by the next one in the alphabet using this mapping:

```
from_str: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
to_str:   bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not `b-(za)`, it is `(b-z)a`.`'a-d'` is just a shortcut for `'abcd'`.

`tr` method (and `tr!`) takes two strings and substitute each occurrence of the each letter in first string with the letter in a second string from the same position (or last letter if second string is shorter). So:

```
'abcdef'.tr('a-d','*')   #=> '****ef'
```

Now the string `'a-z'` is a  shortcut for any letter (down-cased), and you are substituing it with `'b-za'` which is shortcut for `'bcdef...xyza'` so:

```
'abcdefz'.tr('a-z', 'b-za') #=> 'bcdefga'
```